# Cannot get my php to process sqlsrv_connect on my GoDaddy Server

Tags: php, android, sql

I have an android app that i am trying to get connected to my SQL Server.

I have tried countless ways of getting it to work by get a error on my sqlsrv_connect.

Here is the php im tyring to use. I have replaces my read server/credentials with ***

```
<?php

$myServer = "***";
$myUser = "***";
$myPass = "***";
$myDB = "***"; 

//connection to the database
$conn = sqlsrv_connect($myServer, array('UID'=>$myUser, 'PWD'=>$myPass, 'Database'=>$myDB));

$_GET['search'];

//declare the SQL statement that will query the database
$query = "SELECT * FROM dbo.JD";

$data = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql);  

$result = array();

do {
    while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($data, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)){
        $result[] = $row;   
    }
}while ( sqlsrv_next_result($data) );

echo(json_encode($result));

sqlsrv_free_stmt($data);

mssql_close($dbhandle);
?>
```

When processing on a php online test i get this error

Fatal error: Call to undefined function sqlsrv_connect() in [...][...]on line 7

Here my my php info
http://www.bakerabilene.com/phpinfo.php

It shows sqlsrv as a Registered PHP Streams so I don't understand why its not working.

I have also stripped my php down to where it just makes the connection to see if anything was causing the issue, but it still gives me that same error.

I am positive my server/user/pass/db are correct because i use the exact same credentials on my aspx webpage to access SQL server.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the **[Native SQL Driver (Microsoft Drivers 3.0 for PHP for SQL Server)](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=20098)** is installed . Have you asked the Godaddy Team about this ?

Comment: I called GoDaddy and it was very frustrating. They guy was confused why I was trying to even do this and said that it was working on his end. So I dont know if he was even trying. I did find this link that says it does work on GoDaddy http://support.godaddy.com/groups/web-hosting/forum/topic/sqlsrv-drivers/

Comment: How would I check to see if thats installed since its GoDaddy's server?

Comment: @Bignadad, i am not aware of that , since i haven't used PHP with MSSQL. But open a support ticket, send your simple conn.php file to them and tell them why it ain't working.